# How to replace values in numpy matrix columns with values from another array?

Tags: python, numpy

I have 2 numpy arrays:

```
a= np.array([[2, 1, 7],
             [7, 7, 3],
             [1, 7, 4]])


b= np.array([9,-1,17])
```

I would like to change the `7` in each column in `a` with the values from `b`, such that in the first column the `7` is replaced by the first value from `b` and in the second column the `7`s are replaced by the second value from `b` and so on.

My simple solution is:

```
for j in range(len(b)): 
    a[a[:,j]==7,j]=b[j]

array([[ 2,  1, 17],
       [ 9, -1,  3],
       [ 1, -1,  4]])
```

It works, but for very large matrices it is not fast enough. Is there another, faster way to do this?

Comment: `np.where(a == 7, b, a)`

Comment: Thank you. interestingly using `np.where` is much slower than the loop approach for large matrices.

Comment: @user92234 - What is large? I benchmarked your solution vs `np.where` with a 1525mb array shape (100_000, 2000) and got ~2.27x faster runtime with `np.where` on a 2 core google colab instance.

Comment: I tried with (1000000, 800) and got almost 2x as fast with looping.

Comment: That's odd. I can only benchmark shape (500_000,1000) with the available RAM and still ~2.5x faster (5.72s / 1.97s) with `np.where`. `torch.where` is 23122x faster on a Tesla K80 than `np.where`

Comment: How about `a[x] = b[(x := np.nonzero(a == 7))[1]]` then?

Comment: `np.where` should be always faster than the loop except if you do not have enough memory and the system starts to use the swap memory. This is because working on the full 2D array create bigger temporary arrays. As for `torch.where`, I do not think a 23122x speed up is possible unless `torch.where` does not actually compute the result. In fact, most GPU API compute arrays lazily because of the high cost to communicate with the GPU. GPU-friendly APIs can also do that for CPU implementations.

Comment: @JérômeRichard - I thought that, too. Benchmarks **excluded** the time to copy the data to the GPU memory. Pure computation time to get the result was ~85µs vs 1.97s. Warm runs and cold runs. Benchmark was run on a free tier google colab instance with a Tesla K80.

Comment: @MichaelSzczesny I am not talking about the time to copy the input data. I am talking about a lazy computation. How can you be sure that `torch` does the computation when you ask it to do? It can compute the operation lazily when the result is used (eg. printed or computed for something else, but the dependent computations can also be lazily done). The CuPy package does that for example. An array `(500_000,1000)` of 32-bit ints take 1.86 GiB. Computing it in ~85µs means a RAM throughput of 22 TiB/s which is far more than what any GPU in the world can do yet. The K80 can only reach 0.48 TiB/s.

Comment: @MichaelSzczesny In fact, this is an optimistic throughput since one array needs to be written and one needs to be read. Moreover, one should take into account the time to send the GPU kernel request through the PCI-bus/Nvlink and to actually allocate the output array (which takes about dozens of us on mainstream platforms). I think such overheads is what you can measure, not the actual computation time.

Comment: @JérômeRichard - That's true. I think `%%timeit` doesn't work well with GPU workloads. The time to get the results is faster than `np.where`, but definitely not <400ms (timed with counting to 1 in my head ...).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the computed matrices are big, you can implement a **fast parallel version using Numba**. This implementation is much faster than the initial solution using pure-Python loops which create many small temporary arrays and an inefficient non-contiguous memory access pattern (eg. `a[:,j]`). It is also significantly faster than using `np.where(a == 7, b, a)` due to the *huge temporary arrays* that needs to be filled and that *may not fit in RAM* (causing the OS to work with the very slow swap memory). Using multiple threads also provides a big speed up. Here is the code:

```py
import numba as nb

@nb.njit('void(int_[:,::1], int_[::1])', parallel=True)
def compute(a, b):
    n, m = a.shape
    assert b.size == m
    for i in nb.prange(n):
        for j in range(m):
            if a[i,j] == 7:
                a[i,j] = b[j]
```

Here are results on my 6-core machine on a 100000x1000 matrix (with random 32-bit integers in 0..10):

```
For loop:  683 ms
np.where:  169 ms
Numba:      37 ms
```

This version is **18 times faster** than the initial version and takes almost no more memory (it works in-place).

Comment: What does `::1`mean in the signature?

Comment: It mains that the array dimension is *contiguous*. Numba can further optimize the code if it know that when compiling the function. Note that if this is not the case, you can replace it with just a `:`, but I advise you to copy the array if the stride of the last dimension if big for sake for performance (at the expense of a bigger memory footprint).